# Unexpected result when using trigonometric function on KitKat's calculator

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, calculator

I get unexpected results when using the trigonometric functions on my Android 4.4.2 phone.

For example, if I enter `sin(30)=` I get the result `-0.9880316` when I expect the result `0.5`. It appears the phone expects trigonometric numbers to be expressed in radians rather than degrees which is uncommon - the phone's manual certainly did not mention it. Most calculators work in degrees. Decent calculators have a deg/rad/grad switch.

Is there a way to do this on the phone or am I forced to include a degrees-to-radians conversion in all my trig calculations?

Answer (score 4):

This is a known feature / bug, depending on how you look at it. It is even there in Lollipop and [supposed to have been fixed in Marshmallow_bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80330). It is supposed to have the `deg/rad` switch. (Edit: Thanks to benjaminS for [confirming](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143955/android-4-4-2-calculator-trig-function-error/143958#comment185658_143958) that Marshmallow incorporates this). Couple of ways you can get around it:

- Store the conversion value of ( pi/ 180) and multiply by value to convert into radians- very tedious
- Use alternative from Play Store from reviews like [this](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-calculator-apps-577878/)
- Upgrade to Marshmallow if this is important for you. Calculator has additional [features with screen shots](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/06/12/android-m-feature-spotlight-the-stock-calculator-app-has-been-overhauled-no-longer-uses-floating-point-arithmetic/), Thanks to benjaminS again for pointing [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143955/android-4-4-2-calculator-trig-function-error/143958?noredirect=1#comment185661_143958) out.  :)

Comment: I can confirm that there is the option to switch between DEG/RAD in the stock calculator app on Marshmallow. :)

Comment: You can link to [this article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/06/12/android-m-feature-spotlight-the-stock-calculator-app-has-been-overhauled-no-longer-uses-floating-point-arithmetic/) from androidpolice - there are screenshots available which show the difference and the added options quite well